# How to Upper Serbian letters, Č,Ć,Š,Đ,Ž in PHP

Tags: php

I got a problem to make upper letters in php.

I tried this function:

```
function strtouper_srbija($string) {
    $low=array("č" => "Č", "ž" => "Ž", "Š" => "š","Đ" => "đ","Č" => "č");
    return strtoupper(strtr($string,$low));
}
```

and tried to use with some POST data from html page,text filed,but no succes,so if you have solutions,will be fine..

Also, I found solution with CSS, with `text-transform: uppercase;`, but will be fine to have PHP example.

Comment: Try `mb_strtoupper('YOUR TEXT', 'UTF-8')`

Comment: If your example doesn't work, when it should, then you probably have some encoding issues. See this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Plus, your function is `strtoUPPER`, but you are converting uppercase to lowercase, like `"Š" => "š"` etc. Your [function](https://eval.in/84338) should work. What is the exact problem?

Comment: Now work, your example :)

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't you use **mb_strtoupper**?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php

```
<?php
$str = "Τάχιστη αλώπηξ βαφής ψημένη γη, δρασκελίζει υπέρ νωθρού κυνός";
$str = mb_strtoupper($str, 'UTF-8');
echo $str; // Prints ΤΆΧΙΣΤΗ ΑΛΏΠΗΞ ΒΑΦΉΣ ΨΗΜΈΝΗ ΓΗ, ΔΡΑΣΚΕΛΊΖΕΙ ΥΠΈΡ ΝΩΘΡΟΎ ΚΥΝΌΣ
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop trough your string using a `foreach` loop:

```
function strtouper_srbija($string) {
    $letters = array("č" => "Č", "ž" => "Ž", "š" => "Š", "đ" => "Đ", "ć" => "Ć");
    $newString = $string;
    foreach ($letters as $lower=>$upper){
        $newString = str_replace($lower, $upper, $newString);
    }
    return $newString;
    }
```

Other way from [Glavić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67332/glavic)

```
function strtouper_srbija($string) {
    $letters = array("č" => "Č", "ž" => "Ž", "š" => "Š", "đ" => "Đ", "ć" => "Ć");
    return str_replace(array_keys($letters), array_values($letters), $string);
}

echo strtouper_srbija('testiram ščćžđ ŠČĆŽĐ');
```

Comment: You cannot `foreach` a string like that.

Comment: And `$newString;` is a wrong way of declaring a empty variable; if you had error reporting on, you would probably see `Notice: Undefined variable: newString`.

Comment: @Glavić hhh why did you let me strugling with it?

Comment: @Glavić Yes i know that this was your purpose tanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer...
Edit your php script and add function like this:
1:

```
function sumniki($string)
{ 
$sumniki = array("ć", "Ć", "č", "Č", "š", "Š", "ž", "Ž"); 
$koda = array("&#263;", "&#264;", "&#269;", "&#268;", "&#154;", "&#138;", "&#158;", "&#142;"); 

$nova = str_replace($sumniki, $koda, $string); 
return $nova; 
}
```

---

2:
add "sumniki" to your code like this

```
$name = sumniki($_POST['name']);
$email = sumniki($_POST['email']);
```

and so on if you have more...